# How can I map numpad symbols to the symbols these keys represent?

Tags: bash, inputrc

I have bash `5.1.16` and after installing the system, I cannot use numpad symbols in bash. Pressing 5 on the numpad produces number 5 in the command line, but pressing slash or dash symbol has no effect.

I am aware that these keys send different key codes to the remote system, but I would like to map them to their respective variants. I am using PuTTY as the terminal client, if that is relevant.

I'd like to add something to `.bashrc` so that numpad symbols <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> show as the respective characters. I don't want to do this change in my SSH client, because some other tools like `nano` still use these keys for special purposes - I only want to reinterpret them when writing in the bash command line.

I tried to use `showkey -a` to see what is being received for the numpad keys and got this:

```
^[OQ     27 0033 0x1b
         79 0117 0x4f
         81 0121 0x51
```

I then tried to use the `bind` command like this:

```
bind '"^[OQ": /'
```

Nothing happened.